# Jackrabbit :- is jackrabbit supports for open file in read-write mode in MS-Office?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, webdav, jackrabbit

I am creating WEBDAV application using Java-Jackrabbit. For starting I have deployed jackrabbit-webapp-2.4.2.war and running it. It support for adding new file, delete and replace existing file.

But when I am trying to open this file in MS Word It opens it in read-only Mode, And I want to Open It as read-write mode. I have tried same thing with Other demo webdav app and It works fine.

Is it possible to implement with Jackrabbit?